# Object looks fine in rendered mode, but appears black in material mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

So I'm trying to learn, but I have a really hard time understanding the relation between materials, textures, UV maps and so on. So right now I have the following problem: I'm trying to make a simple red texture be a bit grainy using a noise texture. The node setup can be seen in the screenshots below. It works fine if I view it in rendered mode (I'm using the cycles engine) or export a screenshot, but the object appears completely black in material mode:

[image: material mode]

[image: rendered mode]

So this is probably a very stupid question, but do you mind telling me how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a hunch, but try selecting the red diffuse node

Comment: Select it in the node editor you mean? I just did, so?

Comment: Yeah, and then switch back to solid and then to material again. If it doesn't help, you can set the material viewport display settings to a specific color, it just won't update. The Noise texture is what is throwing it off I think

Comment: Still black :/ In solid it appears with the standard grey-ish white of objects that don't have a texture applied by the way

Comment: Alright, it must be the noise texture. I do not know how to do this :/

Comment: The object in Material shading mode is black because **Diffuse** shader with black color is connected to the bottom input. Connect it to the top one and object should become red. Also note that Material shading mode [is approximate and preview procedural textures may not work](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html?highlight=shading%20mode#shading-modes)

Comment: @MrZak Thanks, now it appears red, but stil without the black noise/grain. I'm assuming that's because the noise is produced procedurally and can therefore not be shown in material mode? .. And if that is the case, the factor of the Mix Shader isn't calculated in the Material shading mode, but why does the program only show the bottom input of the Mix shader?

Comment: The Factor is calculated, deconnect your Noise texture, move the Factor slider and notice the color changes (all in Material mode). If you plug Image texture in the Factor instead, you will see basic assignment on mesh (note - texture coordinates should be used too).

Comment: Yeah I meant the noise factor isn't calculated or at least not shown in the Material mode. What do I need texture cordinates for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procedural textures (such as noise) will not render in Material Shading

[image]

> From the [Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html?highlight=shading):
>
> **Shading** refers to the way objects are drawn and lit in the 3D View.
>
> **Rendered**
>
> An accurate representation using the selected Render Engine and lit with the visible scene lights.
>
> **Material**
>
> A fast approximation of the applied material. Some effects, such as procedural textures may not be shown.
>
> **Textured**
>
> Shows meshes with an image applied using the mesh’s active UV Map. For Cycles materials, the image is the last one selected in the Node Editor. For other render engine’s, the UV Map’s applied face texture will be shown.
>
> **Solid**
>
> The default drawing mode using solid colored surfaces and simple lighting.
>
> **Wireframe**
>
> Objects appear as a mesh of lines representing the edges of faces and surfaces.
>
> **Bounding Box**
>   Shows only the rectangular boxes that outlines an object’s size and shape.

When you have a mix node, the color connected used in the bottom socket becomes the one used in the 3D viewport's material shading:

[image]

Comment: Whoa... never knew that part about the bottom socket being used for material preview shading. Is that documented *anywhere* or did you just figure it out by trial and error? A long time ago I gave up on using material preview shading with Cycles because I found it unpredictable and inaccurate. This bit of knowledge changes that a little bit.